# The path to include header files

Tags: c++, qt, qt-creator, qmake

Assuming there is `C:\somelib\headerfromsomelib.h`. I used to put on my `project.pro` the following

```
INCLUDEPATH += C:\somelib
```

And on `file.cpp` I will put

```
#include "headerfromsomelib.h"
```

Then hitting `F2` over it will led me to that header file.

In another approach I can, instead, add `C:\somelib` to the `INCLUDE` environment variable.
So its not necessary to add anything to the pro file. And it still builds.
I found this approach interesting since it adds flexibility, in a project with multiple developers
everyone will be able to have`somelib` in a different path.

However hitting `F2` on the include line on QtCreator will not led me to the header file anymore.
Am I missing something or this is a downside of the this approach?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A more reliable way of using environment variables for library paths is to create environment variables for each library. E.g. create an environment variable `SOMELIB_PATH` then you can do:

```
INCLUDEPATH += $$(SOMELIB_PATH)
```

This can be extended for libraries you need to link to as well:

```
INCLUDEPATH += $$(SOMELIB_PATH)/include
LIBS += -L$$(SOMELIB_PATH)/lib -lsomelib
```

Comment: Sounds good. I’m wondering if this way I can F2 on the include line to reach the header file.

Comment: Where/How/When would you recommend to set those variables? I'm thinking to put a script somewhere and 
run it whenever I need those variables. Would you consider it a good idea?

Comment: Simpler just to set them globally in Windows